# Ionic2-Calendar customize styles

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2-calendar

I hope you are well.

I am using Ionic2-Calendar from : https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar and I want to change the css of the default calendar and I can't find the right way to do it.

The default look is this : [Default Look Ionic2-Calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9P7H.png)

And I would like to make it look like this : [The look how I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7n4OK.png)

Can someone please give me a hint or a suggestion how can I change the css or what should I do to remove the border of the default calendar and to make it with just a capital letter like in the wanted image and how can I style the calander?

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Please Check  Documentation: https://github.com/twinssbc/Ionic2-Calendar#template-customization